# I need to copy all selected datagridview row to another datagridview when checkboxcolumn is checked

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I am attempting to copy datagridview rows to another datagridview when checkboxcolumn is checked. I am loading datagridview1 from treeview when child node is selected. However, when I select another childnode, the previous checkedbox disappears

```
 private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Product Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Qty");
        dt.Columns.Add("Unit Price");

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSelect1.Rows)
        {
           bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value);
            if (isSelected)
                {
               dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[2].Value);
                }
                dgvSelect2.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres your Code snippet

**In your main class:**

```
private DataTable dt;
```

**In the constructor for the main class:**

```
dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Product Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Qty");
dt.Columns.Add("UnitPrice");
dgvSelect2.DataSource = dt;
```

Setting `dt` as `DataSource` for the `DataGrid` links the content of the `DataTable` to the `DataGrid` so you have to do it just once.

**In button click:**

```
dt.Clear();
foreach(var row in dgvSelect1.Rows)
{   
   if ((row.Collumns["checkBoxColumn"].Content as CheckBox).IsChecked)
   {
      var newRow = dt.NewRow();
      newRow["Product Name"] = row["Product Name"];
      /*yadayada*/
      dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
   }
}
```

Let the data grid create the new row so that the columns are defined so that you just have to fill them individually, and then add it to the `DataTable` which will then sync to the `DataGrid`.

Comment: I am getting errors by running it this way. 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and Cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of type 'object'.Errors are on  (row.Cells) and row["Product Name"]